# How to catch Execution exception in scala playframework?

Tags: forms, scala, playframework

I'm getting Execution exception

> [APIError: You must provide an email address in order to create a ticket.]

it is possible to catch this error and post only

> "You must provide an email address in order to create a ticket."

this error should showup in the view page.

the code that give error :

```
val question = uservoice.post("/api/v1/tickets.json", ticket).getJSONObject("ticket")
```

Controller:

```
def contactSave = withOptionUser { user => implicit request =>
    contactForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
      formWithErrors => BadRequest(html.anon.contact(user, formWithErrors)),
      c => {
          val uservoice = new com.uservoice.Client(SUBDOMAIN, API_KEY, API_SECRET)

          val ticketMsg = Map("state" -> "open","subject" -> c._2, "message" -> c._3).toMap[String,Object].asJava

          val ticket = Map("email" -> c._1, "ticket" -> ticketMsg).toMap[String,Object].asJava

          Logger.debug(ticket.toString)

          val question = uservoice.post("/api/v1/tickets.json", ticket).getJSONObject("ticket")

          Logger.debug(question.toString)

          Ok(views.html.anon.contactThanks(user))
      }
    )
  }
```

Html :

```
@main("Contact Us",user,"contact",stylesheet, scripts) {
    @helper.form(routes.UservoiceController.contactSave) {
<section class="contact">
    <div class="contactBox contentBox">
        <div class="leftColumn">
            <h1>Contact Us</h1>
            <span>You can fill out this form for any general inquiries, comments, etc.</span>
            <span>You can also find us on Facebook and Twitter!</span>

            <div class="social">
                @form.globalError.map { error =>
                <span class="error" data-xpl="loginError">
                    @error.message
                </span>
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be checking for a valid email address before posting to that API? Blindly catching all exceptions could mask other bugs down the road.

Comment: Hi Limb, the code is using 3rd party email sending where I can't found how they validate their email.. so I'm thinking to catch the error while trying to figure out the validation used.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a try / catch block and create a form

```
var form = contactForm.bindFromRequest()
form.fold(
  formWithErrors => ...
  c => {
    ...
    try {
      val question = uservoice.post("/api/v1/tickets.json", ticket).getJSONObject("ticket")
      Logger.debug(question.toString)
      Ok(views.html.anon.contactThanks(user))
    } catch {
      case e: Exception =>
        Logger.error("error ...", e)
        val formWithError = form.withError("email", "You must provide an email address in order to create a ticket.")
        BadRequest(html.anon.contact(user, formWithError))
    }
  }
)
```

Comment: Hi @Yann Simon I'm getting value withError is not a member of (String, String, String)

By the way I have this in the view file
@( user: Option[User], 
   form: Form[(String, String, String)]
)

Comment: yes sorry, you must first extract the form instance:
    val form = contactForm.bindFromRequest
    form.fold (
      formWithErrors => ...,
      c => ...
        try {
          ...
        } catch {
          ...
          val formWithError = form.withError(...)
          ...
        }
      )